# Processes are spawned before the MPIPoolExecutor initialization. In addition can I use a HPC with the ProccesPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mpi, mpi4py

I am using the mpi4py library for parallel programming. But it seems that processes are spawned before I creat my MPIPoolExecutor, since I got 4 times the same warning that it lies before the initialization of my Executor. Is this something normal? How can I prevent this?

```
start_time = time.time()

Nodes = pd.read_csv(Csvfile)
fields = SelectCoordinates(Nodes,min_lon = 10, max_lon = 11, min_lat = 49, max_lat = 50)
ts = pd.read_csv(File to be read)

n=6 # number of steps of forecast
p = 2 # number of lags


L = 1000# size of data we will use
ts = ts.iloc[0*L:1*L]

Farms = ts.shape[1]
colnames = ts.columns.values.tolist()
ts=ts.values


# n = fstep # number of time steps ahead
size = int(len(ts) * 0.66) #Determining train and test set
train = np.zeros(shape=(size,Farms))
test = np.zeros(shape=(len(ts)-size,Farms))
train, test = ts[0:size], ts[size:len(ts)]

#=================Intialization================
G = np.zeros(shape=(Farms*p,Farms*p))#
Gt = np.zeros(shape=(Farms*p,Farms*p))#

gn = np.zeros(shape=(Farms*p,1))

b = np.zeros(shape=(Farms*p,Farms))
X = np.zeros(shape=(Farms*p,Farms)) # Coefficient Matrix
#x = np.ones(shape=(Farms*p,1)) # Coefficient Matrix
#x[0] = 1
lamda = 0.001
c = 0.1
v=0.999
T = len(train) 

workers =  MPIPoolExecutor(max_workers = 4)       
for t in range(p,T):

    result_list = []

    to_do = list()


    count = 0 
    for l in range(p):
        for k in range(4):
            gn[count]=train[t-l-1,k]
            count+=1
    G = G*v +  gn @ gn.T
    Gt = (1/(t-p+1))*G

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        for i in range(4):

            job = workers.submit(OULtraining, train[t,i], X[:,i,np.newaxis], b[:,i,np.newaxis], i, gn)

            job.add_done_callback(log_result)
            to_do.append(job)


        for future in cf.as_completed(to_do):
            result_list.append(future.result())

        result_list = sorted(result_list,key=itemgetter(2))
        for i  in range(4):
            X[:,i,np.newaxis], b[:,i,np.newaxis], s = result_list[i]

    if (t%100==0):
        print(t)
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I want to implement a recursive parallel algorithm and I want a MPIpool to be created only once and in each time step do a job wait for all the jobs to finish and then call the processes again with inputs the previous outputs and then again the same at the next time step, etc.

I also get 4 times the print, but I want only the master to do the prints. It seems that the whole program runs 4 times even before I create the executor. If I use the ProcessPoolExecutor with the same code, everything works fine!

And one last qustion. Can I use the ProccesPoolExecutor to work in a HPC with different machines? Or I must use the MPIPoolExecutor? In addition I found out that In OpenMPI, name == "main" won’t work because in all processes name == "main". The OpenMPI equivalent is: os.environ['OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK'] == '0'. But when I use this I got this error: KeyError: 'OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK' Do you have any information about this?

Comment: So you posted code from the part of your program after the warning occurs.  What about the code before?  The code after is irrelevant!

Comment: *it seems that processes are spawned before I creat my MPIPoolExecutor*  Yes, that's not unusual for MPI.  The run time system starts up the number of processes requested in the job submission so individual processes will be running prior to any MPI statements.  It's generally a feature of the platform you're using, not something you have control over, nor anything to cause concern.

Comment: My problem is that, it is really slower compare to my ProcessPoolExecutor of the concurrent future implementation. Is there any trivia reason for this?

Comment: It seems that it runs a part of the code 4 times. So it is something that I have to worry. It loads the same big data structures many times!

Comment: Actually every process runs the part of the code, before the creation of the Pool, and I can not control this. There should be a way to limit this.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation at http://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mpi4py.futures.html#mpipoolexecutor

> MPIPoolExecutor takes advantage of the dynamic process management features introduced in the MPI-2 standard. In particular, the MPI.Intracomm.Spawn() method of MPI.COMM_SELF() is used in the master (or parent) process to spawn new worker (or child) processes running a Python interpreter. The master process uses a separate thread (one for each MPIPoolExecutor instance) to communicate back and forth with the workers. The worker processes serve the execution of tasks in the main (and only) thread until they are signaled for completion.

My understanding is that MPI tasks of the pool are dynamically spawned, so you should really start only one MPI task (e.g. `mpirun -np 1 ...`)

Answer (score 1):

As written in the documentation, you have to start the application using the

```
$ mpiexec -n numprocs python -m mpi4py.futures pyfile
```

Please read the examples category at the bottom of this documentation page: 
https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mpi4py.futures.html#mpipoolexecutor

Answer (score 1):

everything that is not protected by `if __name__ == '__main__':` will be run by every mpi rank.